# Creating Windows service from Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, windows-services

how can I run this powershell script as a Windows Service?

```
$olSaveType = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType" -as [type] 

Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" $Outlook =
New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application $Namespace =
$Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 

$EmailsInFolder= $NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Items
$EmailsInFolder | ft SentOn, Subject, Sensitivity -AutoSize -Wrap

foreach ($EmailInFolder in $EmailsInFolder)        
{
   $EmailInFolder.Subject = "Test" 
   $EmailInFolder.Save()
}
```

I like to change the email subject when I move the email in a folder.

Regards
Stefan

Comment: I'm no Office dev expert, but surely there is a way to program Outlook to do this? Some kind of rule or macro?  Seems very heavy-handed having a system service to manage your email for you, especially one written in a language not designed for that type of development.

Comment: To add to @boxdog's comment: Using the COM-based Automation libraries isn't supported in Window services - see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Answer (score 1):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.
>
> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

As a workaround, you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or any other wrapper around that API such as Redemption.

Or, if you deal with Exchange profiles only, you may consider using EWS, see [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot use Outlook (or any other Office app) from a service.
Secondly, an Outlook COM addin might be a better solution  - it always runs when Outlook is running, so there is no need for a Windows service.